# store object in an array using ansi c?

Tags: c, visual-c++, c89

I make a structure just like

```
struct abc {
    //any function or variable
} obje[20];
```

now I want that the each object of `abc` store in array. means that `arr[0]` contain `obj[0]` only; can it is possible. if it is possible then some one help me in this matter.

Comment: I suspect we still don't know enough about what you are trying to achieve to be truly helpful beyond a tutorial about arrays in C. Can you extend the question with some code showing what you've tried and explain what problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the objects from the array `obje` into the array `arr`, you can use `memcpy()` from `<string.h>`:

```
#include <string.h>

struct abc arr[20];

memcpy(&arr, &obje, sizeof arr);

/* Now arr[0] has a copy of obje[0], arr[1] has a copy of obje[1], ... */
```